# Identifying whether the sequence $2n+(-1)^n$ is monotonically increasing/decreasing and if it is limited.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

(First of all, sry for some spelling and similar mistakes as English is not my native language.)

I tried to prove, that the sequence $2n+(-1)^n$ is monotonically increasing, that's what I assume from some values I calculated within the interval $[-10,10]$.

I used the following equation: $$a_n \leq a_{n+1} $$ $$\Leftrightarrow 0 \leq a_{n+1}-a_n$$

I equated
$a_{n+1} = 2(n+1)+(-1)^{n+1}; a_n = 2n+1(-1)^n$

$\Leftrightarrow 0 \leq 2(n+1)+(-1)^{n+1}-2n+1(-1)^n$

$\Leftrightarrow 0 \leq 2n+2+(-1)^{n+1}-2n+1(-1)^n$

$\Leftrightarrow 0 \leq 2+(-1)^{n+1}+1(-1)^n $

$\Leftrightarrow 0 \leq 2+ \underbrace{(-1)^{n+1}+1(-1)^n}_{=0}$

$\Leftrightarrow 0 \leq 2$

This would prove that $2n+(-1)^n$ is strictly monotonically increasing, which is not the case here. The function is only monotonically increasing. What went wrong?

The function has no limits as I could figure out from function-plotters, but I'm still unable to create a formal prove for that. Can you help me with that?
I would just prove that the sequence is approaching infinity:

$$2n+1(-1)^n$$
$$\underbrace{\underbrace{\underbrace{2n}_{2\cdot\infty=\infty}+1}_{\infty+1=\infty}\underbrace{(-1)^n}_{=\pm1}}_{\infty\pm1=\infty}$$ This shows that the sequence is approaching infinity. Is that enough to prove it's not limited?

Thanks in advance,

$Doesbaddel$

Comment: The word commonly used is “bounded” rather than “limited”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try and simplify:
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}-a_n
&=(2(n+1)+(-1)^{n+1})-(2n+(-1)^n) \\[4px]
&=2n+2+(-1)^{n+1}-2n-(-1)^n \\[4px]
&=2+(-1)(-1)^n-(-1)^n \\[4px]
&=2-2(-1)^n \\[4px]
&=2(1-(-1)^n) \\[4px]
&=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{$n$ even} \\
4 & \text{$n$ odd}
\end{cases} \\[4px]
&\ge0
\end{align}
Indeed, $a_0=2\cdot0+(-1)^0=1$, $a_1=2\cdot1+(-1)^1=1$, $a_2=2\cdot2+(-1)^2=5$, $a_3=2\cdot3+(-1)^3=5$ and so on.

Can you spot your mistake?

Thus the sequence is not strictly increasing, but increasing nonetheless.

You can also see that $a_0=1$, $a_2=5$, $a_4=9$, and prove that $a_{2n}=4n+1$ by induction, so the sequence is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I forgot to differentiate between odd and even numbers. In case of odd numbers, the sequence a_n will be the same as a_n+1, that's why the sequence is not strictly monotonically increasing.

Comment: I just noticed that I forgot to change one mathematical operator in order to do subtractions.

Comment: That's not the mistake you mean, right?

Comment: Why do you write (2 (n + 1) - (-1)^n + 1) - (2n - (-1)^n) and not (2 (n + 1) + (-1)^n + 1) - (2n  - (-1)^n)?

Comment: @Doesbaddel Sorry, fixed.

Comment: Alright, I understand everything now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $n$ is even, say $$n=2m$$ we get $$2(2m)+(-1)^{2m}=4m+1$$
If $n$ is odd, say $$n=2m+1$$ then we get $$2(2m+1)+(-1)^{2m+1}=4m+2-1=4m+1$$
in both cases.

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot that more than one case excists, because it's an alternating sequence.

Comment: and in both even and odd cases $m=\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ and the expression can be written $$ 2n + (-1)^n = 4\lfloor \tfrac{n}{2} \rfloor + 1  $$

Comment: However, the main thing is that you can solve your problem!

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson How did you came to this conclusion? (I know it's right, but I can't replicate it and now I feel dumb.)

Comment: when $n$ is even (that is $n=2m$) then $$ m = \tfrac{n}{2} = \lfloor \tfrac{n}{2} \rfloor . $$  when $n$ is odd (that is $n=2m+1$) then $$ m = \tfrac{n-1}{2} = \lfloor \tfrac{n}{2} \rfloor . $$  from the definition of the `floor()` function, $\lfloor x \rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}$ is an integer such that
$$ x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x $$

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Thank you. I couldn't figure it out although it was obvious, sorry for wasting your time :D

Comment: it's not a waste.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson By the way, sry that you lost the "Accepted Answer" mark. I forgot, that only one answer can be marked as "accepted".

Comment: first i gotta make an answer.  i hadn't made time for that.  if my comments suffice to communicate to you what was intended, why not leave it at that?  you can accept someone else's answer (if you think it's acceptable).  but if you want me to, i will put together an answer tonight (U.S. Left coast).  maybe in 6 hours.

Answer (score 1):

For all $n$, we have

$$u_n=2n+(-1)^n\ge 2n-1$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(2n-1)=+\infty\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}u_n=+\infty$$

$(u_n)$ has no upper bound.

Comment: Thank you, I will change that on my sheet.

Comment: Why do you use 2n-1 for the upper limit? Is it, because the sequence will be smaller than 2n+1 when n=even? @hamam_Abdallah

Answer (score 0):

For "strictly", you need $<$! Hence, there is nothing wrong.

You could also prove that $(a_n)_n$ is unbounded, but hamams answer is the fastet way, I guess.